# A grid class with preconfigerd dockedItems,features,

Tags: extjs4

I want to build a reusable grid class with A grid class with preconfigerd dockedItems,features, viewConfig ,....
How can I make it?
How should I declare object config?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [ExtJS 4 class system guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/class_system).

Define classes with:

```js
Ext.define('NewClassName', {
    extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.newclassalias',
    dockedItems : myDockedItems,
    ...
});
```